# How do I reuse an existing branch name as a new branch?

Tags: git

My intent was to have a dev branch that I would create feature branches off.  Those feature branched would be merged into the dev branch and the dev branch would then be merged back to master.  Some how I managed to screw that up and I left my dev branch behind, so here is what I now have.

[image]

I think after merging the password_rest_and_activation_support branch into master, I could just create a new "dev" branch, called "dev-new" or "development",  but I seems like I should be able somehow reuse the "dev" name, but I am not sure how to do this.  I was thinking of just deleting the existing dev branch and creating a new one?  What the right way to do this, given that the dev branch is also on a remote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git checkout master 
git branch -D dev
```

(forcefully delete local `dev`)

```
git push origin :dev
```

(delete remote `dev`)

```
git checkout -b dev
```

(create a new local `dev` branch)

```
git push origin dev
```

(push new `dev` to origin)

For some non-destructive options, including branch renaming, see [**torek's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853556/1264804).

Answer (score 10):

Fundamentally, branch names work like little sticky-note labels.

You may remove a label entirely:

```
git branch -d foo
```

This finds the label with the word "foo" on it (this label is stuck on one particular commit) and peels that label off and throws it (the label, again) away.<sup>1</sup>

Or, you may erase the name on a label and write a new name on it:

```
git branch -m old new
```

The label is still stuck on the same commit, but now it has a different name.

Or, you may move a label from one commit to another:

```
git branch -f moved 1f0c9447
```

The last argument here is a raw commit SHA-1, but you may use anything that locates some commit, such as another branch name.

There *are* some important differences between "delete and recreate", "rename", and "move", because these labels also retain history, of which commit they named before the last time they were moved.  If you delete a label entirely, the history disappears too.  If you rename a label, it retains its history, and if you move a label, it acquires a new history-entry because you moved it from one commit to another.

When you make a new commit, whatever branch you're on, that branch label moves *automatically*, to point to the new commit.  This label-move is recorded in its history.

Use whichever option makes the most sense (do you want history retained or augmented, or do you just want it tossed out?).

(Note that when you create a new branch:

```
git branch new
```

you can supply a raw commit SHA-1, or anything that finds a commit.  So `git branch new existing` will make new branch `new` pointing to the same commit as `existing`.)

---

The branch history is kept in each branch's ["reflog"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html).  There's a ref-log for `HEAD` as well, and `git reflog` shows you that one, but `git reflog show foo` shows the history for reference (usually, branch) `foo`.

This history is normally kept for 90 days.<sup>2</sup>  Furthermore, it's purely local: it does not get copied on `git clone` and `git fetch`, nor pushed with `git push`.

---

As a side note, tags are almost exactly the same as branches, with two big differences other than just the word "tag": they're never *supposed* to move (and won't move automatically), and they don't record a history (because they're not supposed to *need* one).  "Remote branches", aka remote-tracking branches, are a bit of a cross between these.  *You* don't move them, not even by making commits, but they *do* move: when your git contacts the remote and picks up new commits, it also picks up branch-label moves, and updates your remote-tracking branches and their reflogs.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can do this at any time with any label (with `-D`, uppercase), but if you remove the *last* label that finds some commit(s), those commits go invisible—you won't see them in `gitk --all` displays any more, for instance—and eventually (after about a month) they will get garbage-collected.

<sup>2</sup>As usual with git, it's actually a lot more complicated than that: there are two different reflog expiry values, one for "reachable" objects and one for "unreachable" objects.  The 90 day default is for reachable objects; unreachable objects default to 30 days; and both values can be configured.

In addition, the special `stash` ref (used by [`git stash`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html)) has its default expiry set to "never", so that stashes don't expire.

Comment: "because these labels also retain history, of which commit they named before the last time they were moved. If you delete a label entirely, the history disappears too" --- uhm, could you please shed some light on this? Is there a separated graph for metadata changes?

Comment: "This label-move is recorded in its history." --- and on this please. I haven't ever seen what you're talking about.

Comment: from what I know: 1. git reflog is local only 2. it is cleaned up during gc. Keeping that in mind - is it *that important* to retain the history (as soon as it is local and will be lost anyway)?

Comment: does the -m old new method work for the remote as well?

Comment: @nPn: not with `git branch`, which won't move anything but a branch; and `git update-ref` does not have a "move" option, so to get that to work right you have to copy the reflog.  In general remote reflogs are only updated on `git remote update` or `git fetch` anyway, though.

Comment: @torek I should have thought of renaming the branch in the first place, and while it probably was not critical to rename it on the remote, I followed isherwood's and zerkms's (and my initial instinct), and deleted the old branch and created a new branch.  Don't know why I was so nervous about this.

Comment: Incidentally, if you run `git fetch` or `git remote update` with `-p` / `--prune`, that will delete from your remote-tracking branches any branches that are now gone on the remote.  So if you want to rename the branch on the remote, you can simply (?) push the old label to the new name, then push to delete the old name, then run `git fetch -p` to get your own remote-tracking branches updated.